# Is there any way to move and take a job (as a barista) in the United States as a foreigner?

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas

I am considering moving and working in the United States for a period of three months.

However the job position that I would like to apply for (barista) does not allow me to get a work visa.
(I am not a citizen or permanent resident of the United States so in order to start working I need to provide an Employment Authorization Document as well as a Social Security card which require having this type of visa first). I wanted to ask what kind of visa I could apply for in my situation or if there would be any other way to make it happen?

Comment: Your question has the answer. To work you need a work visa, and you can't get a work visa for this type of work.

Comment: @jcaron you can if you're a student, tons of baristas are on the J-1 visa

Comment: @JonathanReez - Good luck making enough money to pay for college on a part-time barista salary. If you are coming to the US to earn money, and not to spend it.

Comment: @Obie2.0 J-1 is a visa for students in countries abroad and is precisely designed for summer jobs

Comment: It is for, among other groups, people who want to come to study and also offset the costs of their education somewhat. If your goal is to make money, as the question indicates, that is a different matter. Paying for a year or even a semester of university in order to work for three months over the summer is unlikely to be a very profitable proposition.

Comment: Oh, unless you mean the J-1 Summer Work Travel Program, as opposed to the other J-1 visas. Sure, in that case I agree. But they would have to be a student with at least one completed semester.

Comment: @Obie2.0 yes, the "Work and Travel" program